# rails server return error "libssl.so.1.0.0 The specified module could not be found"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to run Rails version : 5.2.1.1 on Microsoft windows.

Rails 5.2.1.1 ruby 2.7.1p83 (2020-03-31 revision a0c7c23c9c) [x64-mingw32]

I installed all the required gems ruby and all thing
but whenever i tried to run command `rails server` it gives me error like below...

```
could not open library 'libssl.so.1.0.0.dll': The specified module could not be found.
Could not open library 'libssl.so.10': The specified module could not be found.
Could not open library 'libssl.so.10.dll': The specified module could not be found.
Could not open library 'libssl1.0.0': The specified module could not be found.
Could not open library 'libssl1.0.0.dll': The specified module could not be found.
Could not open library 'ssl': The specified module could not be found.
Could not open library 'ssl.dll': The specified module could not be found.
```

I installed openssl but it still does not work.

Comment: what version of rails?  do you get any errors running `bundle install`?

Comment: Rail version : 2.7.1 and i don't get any error using `bundle install`

Comment: Rails 2.7.1?  there's no such version. Do you mean Ruby 2.7.1? So, which version of Rails?

Comment: Rails 5.2.1.1  
ruby 2.7.1p83 (2020-03-31 revision a0c7c23c9c) [x64-mingw32]